# Select the strings that uses a specific font

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have not found a solution for aligning strings for specific font

I searched for information on Google. Some people said that I can use a script to solve it. I haven't used it yet. Any suggestions are welcome.

In my file, there are two font strings, I need to select them separately then align them.

E.g:

file down link:

https://yadi.sk/i/cAqAOqfr7fa5TQ

1. Select the strings that use the **calibri** font
2. Align bottoms
3. Move the strings right 3 pixels

4.Select the strings that use **Arial** fonts

5. Align bottoms
6. Move the strings down 3 pixels

Please see the picture below

[image]

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a scriptwriting service. can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56927178/edit) to provide us with what you have so far? It would also be useful to know what kind of objects the text is in.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reminder, the above question, I tried a lot of methods, for example, I recorded the action, but did not solve it.